# How to add multiple markers easily in Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere-pro

I am making an almost slide show video clip in Premiere pro 2022.

Some part of the music I am using contains regular (I think) notes with mathematical sequence.
For example the music beats patern are almost like this at the end of each peak:  `D ----- D ---- D --- D -- D - D` (steps are 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1). It contains many parts like this with various max steps.

For example consider **Beethoven's Moonlight** or **Fur Elise**.

**Q 1:** I wonder if there is any way to add markers according to a certain pattern, for example according to mathematical sequences?

**Q 2:** If the answer to Q 1 is negative, How to add multiple markers with equal spacing with specified distance between any two markers?

**P.S.** I am aware of Edit Beats Premiere Plugin.